# Desktop file didnt specify exec field

Tags: apt, software-installation

I  downloaded coq-proof Through ubuntu software but whenever I open it I always get that (Desktop file didnt specify exec field) message what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have misspelled the software name. It is shipped as Snap and [named](https://snapcraft.io/coq-prover)

> Coq Interactive Theorem Prover - `coq-prover`.

This Snap seems to be really broken in terms of broken launcher file.

So you have two options:

- manually create a launcher to file named `/snap/bin/coqide` and continue to use this Snap version of application.
- remove this broken Snap by

  ```
  snap remove coq-prover
  ```

  and install deb-packaged version instead by

  ```
  sudo apt-get install coqide
  ```

  and use its preinstalled launcher.

Comment: Thanks! It worked!